# Matrix representation of spin-1/2 system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, linear-algebra, dispersion

Problem 1.19 from Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics asks you to find $\left< (\Delta S_x)^2 \right> = \left< s_x^2 \right> - (\left< s_x \right>)^2 $ in the $S_z +$ state. 
However, $S_x^2$ can be computed in its matrix form by 
$$
S_x^2 = \left( \frac{\hbar}{2} \right)^2
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
1  & 0
\end{pmatrix}^2 
= \left( \frac{\hbar}{2} \right)^2
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Or in its bra-ket form as 
$$ S_x^2 = \left( \frac{\hbar}{2} \right)^2 \left[ \left( |+\rangle\langle-| + |-\rangle\langle+| \right) \left( |+\rangle\langle-| + |-\rangle\langle+| \right) \right] 
= \frac{\hbar^2}{4} \left( |+\rangle\langle+| + |-\rangle\langle-| \right) 
= \frac{\hbar^2}{4} $$
But are these not different results? 
The first one is a matrix and the other is a scalar, or am I missing something in the first computation?
I am aware that when $\left< S_x^2 \right> $ is finally calculated, both answers give $\left< S_x^2 \right> = \frac{\hbar^2}{4} $, however, I would appreciate some clarification as to why the two results for $S_x^2$ aren't conflicting, when matrices and scalars are different mathematical objects, let alone fundamentally different in the physical interpretation of the bra-ket formalism.

Comment: It's the scalar $\dfrac{\hbar^2}{4}$ times the identity matrix, but  the identity matrix can be omitted when computing averages. In some other computations the presence of the identity operator does matter e.g. when computing the trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second result is a constant times the identity operator, which in matrix representation corresponds to the identity matrix.

It is a common notation practice in quantum mechanics to denote both the identity operator and the unit matrix using the symbol 1, or even drop it altogether if it is part of a product. The only inconsistency in your results is that you've been more lax in your notation on the second expression than you've been with the first.